# error using MIL tracker and tracking header

Tags: opencv

Hi guys below is my code and i am getting error in create(const String& TrackerMIL), i am getting error as in this link exactly https://pastebin.com/0x52tJL6,, please help, for you all to know i have added extra module opencv_contrib in opencv3. please help guys. Thanks

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <opencv2/tracking/tracking.hpp>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Set up tracker.
    // Instead of MIL, you can also use
    // BOOSTING, KCF, TLD, MEDIANFLOW or GOTURN
    Ptr<Tracker> Tracker::create( const String& TrackerMIL );

    // Read video
    VideoCapture video("videos/chaplin.mp4");

    // Check video is open
    if(!video.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Could not read video file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Read first frame.
    Mat frame;
    video.read(frame);

    // Define an initial bounding box
    Rect2d bbox(287, 23, 86, 320);

    // Uncomment the line below if you
    // want to choose the bounding box
    // bbox = selectROI(frame, false);

    // Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
    tracker->init(frame, bbox);

    while(video.read(frame))
    {
        // Update tracking results
      tracker->update(frame, bbox);

        // Draw bounding box
      rectangle(frame, bbox, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 2, 1 );


      // Display result
      imshow("Tracking", frame);
      int k = waitKey(1);
      if(k == 27) break;

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: i corrected that issue with create(); but now its this one :( https://pastebin.com/0kP3zzfi

Comment: even if i include my libraries as opencv2_tracking, etc its not working out, i am on eclipse  .. and its all in /usr/local/include

Comment: its done,, build finsished,, now that i am running ./tracker .. its throwing me ./tracker: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_tracking.so.3.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

this is solved after including headers properly specially for the above error  where it was not able to find my libopencv_tracking.so.3.2,, i had to sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade .. and now its working all fine ,,

thanks